# How get class of parent view controller

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have a view controller A that presents has a modal segue which presentes a `UINavigationController` which has as root view controller another view controller B.

How to know the class of view controller A from view controller B?

Preferably using a delegate as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override `UINavigationController` and add a weak property for the controller A. Then you can access that property from the controller B, and get its class name.

Comment: How can i override the uinavigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ([self.navigationController.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerA class]){
       //do stuff
    }
    else{
       //it's view controller b, do stuff
    }
```

Comment: the class that gives this code is the uinavigation controller